# Receiving Email body and Subject but unable to receive Opportunity Details

Tags: apex, batch

I have been getting email but only the subject and body but not receiving any details of the for loop their is no error showing and the batch class is running proprerly

````
    list<String> oppids = new list<String>();    //for storing ids
    public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){    //Start Method
        return database.getQueryLocator([Select Id,Name, CloseDate, StageName From Opportunity Where IsClosed = False]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> records){    //Execute Method
        list<Opportunity> updatedopp = new list<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity obj:records){
            
            Date Extra10 = obj.CloseDate.addDays(10);
            if(Extra10 == Date.today())
            {   
                obj.stagename = 'Closed Won';
                
                updatedopp.add(obj);
                oppids.add(obj.Id); 
                System.debug(oppids);//Storing id of updated opp.
            }
        }
        update updatedopp;    //Updating opp. in database
    }
    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){    //Finish Method
        List<String> idList = new List<String>();
        List<String> mailToAddresses = new List<String>();
        
        //Getting members from group
        Group gp = [SELECT (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group WHERE DeveloperName = 'BatchGrp'];    
        if(gp != null && gp.GroupMembers !=null && !gp.GroupMembers.isEmpty())
            for (GroupMember gm : gp.GroupMembers) {
                idList.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
            }
        
        //Query for getting email addresses
        List< User> userList = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :idList];    
        for(User u : userList) {
            mailToAddresses.add(u.email);
        }        
        if (oppids != null ) {
            
            //Query for details of worked opp.
            List<Opportunity> oppdetails = [SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppids];    
            if (oppdetails != null) {
                String emailBody = 'The following opportunities have been automatically closed:\n\n';
                
                for (Opportunity opp : oppdetails) {
                    emailBody += 'Opportunity ID: ' + opp.Id + '\n';
                    emailBody += 'Opportunity Name: ' + opp.Name + '\n';
                    emailBody += 'Close Date: ' + opp.CloseDate + '\n';
                    emailBody += 'Stage: ' + opp.StageName + '\n\n';
                    
                }
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setSubject('Opportunity Details');
                email.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
                email.setToAddresses(mailToAddresses); 
                
                // Set recipient email address
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] emailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ email });
                
                // Check if the email was sent successfully
                if (emailResults[0].isSuccess()) {    
                    System.debug('Email sent successfully.');
                } else {
                    System.debug('Email failed to send: ' + emailResults[0].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: does your batch class implement `Database.Stateful`?